# What change do I need to make to my jquery to perform a transition effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery to make css changes on my website and am having problems with some of the code. I am a novice using jquery and am usually able to figure it out when I make changes but this one has me stumped.

I have included fragments of my MTML, CSs and Jquery below. What I am attempting to do is underline my link on a hover and at the same time, change the background and link color when someone scrolls down the page. Everything works fine except I can't figure out what the put into my jquery code to have the underline appear when the used scrolls down.

Any help will be appreciated. I realize the answer is probably very simple but I am not sure what I need to have the jquery change.

I have intentionally left out the code that doesn't work but am guessing I need to add code with the if statement in the jquery. This is where I have been trying to add a statement but nothing I have inserted has worked.

I almost forgot to add that the code underlines the link on a hover (same color as the link) and I want to do the same when the page scrolls down (if the link is normally blue with a white background the hover underline is blue also, after scrolling down, the background color becomes blue and the link is gold. I want the underline to be gold also).

Thanks,

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // 100 = The point you would like to fade the nav in.

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.bg').addClass('show');
    $('nav li a').css('color', '#FFCF01');
  } else {
    $('.bg').removeClass('show');
    $('nav li a').css('color', '#00529C');

  };
});

$('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
}

.hdrmenu ul {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
}

.hdrmenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.hdrmenu li a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #00529C;
}

.show {
  background-color: #00529C;
  color: #FFCF01;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.slide-left-right {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFCF01;
  /* yellow gold */
  float: left;
}


/* add a empty string after the elment with class .slide-left-right */

.slide-left-right:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .7s ease, background-color .7s ease;
  /* .5 seonds for changes to the width and background-color */
  -webkit-transition: width .7s ease, background-color .7s ease;
  /* Chrome and Safari */
  -moz-transition: width .7s ease, background-color .7s ease;
  /* FireFox */
}


/* Change the width and background on hover, aka sliding out */

.slide-left-right:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00529C;
  /* lc blue */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="bg transition">
  <nav class="hdrmenu">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="_images/logo.gif" class="logo"></a>
    <ul style="float: right;">
      <li><a href="one.html" class="slide-left-right">Diabetes</a></li>
      <li><a href="two.html" class="slide-left-right">Vision</a></li>
      <li><a href="three.html" class="slide-left-right">Hunger</a></li>
      <li><a href="four.html" class="slide-left-right">Environmental Issues</a></li>
      <li><a href="five.html" class="slide-left-right">Childhood Cancer</a></li>
      <li><a href="six.html" class="slide-left-right boldLi">We Serve</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
     $('.bg').addClass('show');
     $('nav li a').css('color', '#FFCF01');
     $('nav li a').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
 } else {
     $('.bg').removeClass('show');
     $('nav li a').css('color', '#00529C');
     $('nav li a').css('text-decoration', 'none');
 };
```

Comment: This underlines the link which I could do in my css -> hover event.  What I want is to so is have .slide-left-right transition to work the same as it does when the page is located at the top of the browser window, except the color will now be #FFCF01.

Comment: Thanks though for the quick response.